# WPF application manifest file

Tags: c#, wpf, manifest

I have a WPF application that I want to make it able to start always as an Adminstrator. I've been reading a lot about it and it seems that I have to create my own manifest file and pass it to the Application properties so that on runtime it starts as an Administrator.

The application itself loads a file and sometimes the file might demand administrator access so it can be modified. That is why I am looking for a way after the Application gets installed to be able to always get started in administrator mode.

Comment: To create the manfiest, right-click your project, select Add new item..., and choose the Application Manifest type.

Answer (score 54):

To add a Manifest, **right click** on your **project file** in **Solution Explorer**:

1. Select **Add**
2. **New item**
3. Choose **Application Manifest File**

The file should be named **app.manifest**. Don't rename it.

---

You have to change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element in your **Manifest** to start always as an Adminstrator:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

---

BTW: A good article for this question:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-security-overview

Comment: You can't do it when publishing with ClickOnce.

Comment: Why not? According to MSDN it's the same XML specification: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1c2fch.aspx

Comment: Well, I added the manifest file, changed the line you told and try to publish a ClickOnce version. The result is an error: "ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator''.

Comment: To start as admin I did a workaround that starts a new process as Admin and kill the current wich is not admin. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Basic, the project properties are structured a little differently.  If you find this question and you're in VB in VS2010, follow these instructions to generate an *app.manifest* file.

1. To create an **app.manifest** file, go to your project, and select properties.  Then click on **View Window Settings**, under the *Application* tab.

   - [image: ViewWindowSettings]
2. This should generate and open the **app.manifest** file, which is saved in your **My Project Folder**

   - [image: app.manifest]

**Further Reading:** [WPF MessageBox window style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187421/1366033)